# Dataflow access to pubsub access tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When running my apache beam / google dataflow pipeline locally, the python SDK seems to request a new auth token on each input into the streaming pipeline - is this normal?

```
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
```

Comment: Hi @dendog, do you know if this is coming from your code or the SDK? Do the logs have any line number associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2264, however the solution there will not solve this issue.
In any case, this is not normal (DirectRunner is probably multiple new clients) but also probably okay for running most local jobs.